# Biopython for Loop IndexError

Tags: loops, for-loop, biopython

I get "IndexError: list is out of range" when I input this code. Also, the retmax is set at 614 because that's the total number of results when I make the request. Is there a way to make the retmode equal to the number of results using a variable that changes depending on the search results?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "something@gmail.com"
handle1 = Entrez.esearch(db = "nucleotide", term = "dengue full genome", retmax = 614) 
record = Entrez.read(handle1)
IdNums = [int(i) for i in record['IdList']]

while i >= 0 and i <= len(IdNums):
handle2 = Entrez.esearch(db = "nucleotide", id = IdNums[i], type = "gb", retmode = "text")
record = Entrez.read(handle2)
print(record)
i += 1
```

Comment: I made a typo: handle2's definition has an and parenth.

Comment: Please update your code to reflect the changes you made -- then we can go from there.

Comment: Ok, I just fixed the typo. But I'm still having trouble with the out of bounds error with for loop's interaction with IdNums[i].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a while loop, you can use a for loop...

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = 'youremailaddress'
handle1 = Entrez.esearch(db = 'nucleotide', term = 'dengue full genome', retmax = 614)
record = Entrez.read(handle1)
IdNums = [int(i) for i in record['IdList']]

for i in IdNums:
   print(i)
   handle2 = Entrez.esearch(db = 'nucleotide', term = 'dengue full genome', id = i, rettype = 'gb', retmode = 'text')
   record = Entrez.read(handle2)
   print(record)
```

I ran it on my computer and it seems to work. The for loop solved the out of bounds, and adding the term to handle2 solved the calling error.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to help. **If** the code answers your query -- consider accepting the solution.